Is there an efficient algorithm for uniformly sampling subgraphs from a Cayley graph?
Setting: I have a Cayley graph $G=(V,E)$ where each vertex represents a permutation of $n$ elements and an edge exists between vertices $v'$ and $v$ if the permutation associated with $v'$ can be obtained by swapping two elements in the permutation associated with $v$.
Problem: Given a vertex $v \in V$ and a positive integer $t<n!$, uniformly sample all connected subgraphs that contain $v$ and have exactly $t$ vertices.
I know that subgraph sampling can be tricky, but I'm hoping that the structure of the graph (i.e. the fact that it's $d$-regular and vertex-transitive), and the fact that we only need subgraphs containing $v$, will allow for an efficient solution. Thanks!
